# Unexpected symbol 'dim' with a OLEDB connection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oledb

How do I fix this error? I'm using asp.net

Compilation Error

Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Compiler Error Message: CS1519: Unexpected symbol `Dim' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

## Source code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>


<script runat="server">
sub Page_Load
Dim dbconn As OleDbConnection
dbconn=New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;
Data source='http://localhost';
User Id='90782';
Password='@ER#82L(*&!';")
dbconn.Open()
end sub
</script>
```

PS: Double quote added, but this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: For one thing, you have an unterminated string.

Answer (score 2):

you have not closed your double quotes (")

Comment: Damned, I forgot that too... I just saw that with the code highlighting. But sadly, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>

<script runat="server">
      sub Page_Load
         Dim dbconn As OleDbConnection
         dbconn=New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;
                   Data source='http://localhost';
                   User Id='90782';
                   Password='@ER#82L(*&!';")
         dbconn.Open()
      end sub
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
...
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
...
```

Or this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
```

Comment: No... :( CS1041: Identifier expected   
Line 5: Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Comment: Shucks...:-)  How about the page directive -- have you specified VB as your language?  amended answer above.

Comment: No... :( But the problem was the 'dim', according to the compiler. The result was CS1041: Identifier expected   
Line 5: Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) By adding <%@ Page Language="VB" %> results in: Error running vbnc: Cannot find the specified file. Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what else you've got going on in the page/project.  One approach (it's the hands-up approach :-) is to create a new aspx page by r-clicking the folder in visual studio, add new item..., and then in the dropdowns at the top of the page, select 'page' on the left, and 'load' on the right.  You're page will be working up to that point -- then start moving other code into it from your non-functining page -- sometimes it will just work (mystery error), and sometimes it will point you right to the problem.